# Firebase: Don't register my own events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I don't want Firebase to register my events while I'm testing my Android app. What's the best way to get this?

I have a version of my app in the Google Play and I've created a flag for the version in development:

```
if (!test_mode) {
    FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = 
                FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(OperacionActivity.this);
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 1);
                mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("RateNo", params);
}
```

test_mode is a global variable for all the project and all the Firebase uses.

But I suppose there is a better way.

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` while debugging:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

This will temporary disable Analytics collection as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics)

Comment: Thanks! It works and it's an easier solution.